# How to select a object option in angular controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html

I have a select with options getting from server

```
<div class="form-group">
<label for="exampleInputEmail1">Terminal Type</label> 
<select ng-model="terminal.terminalType" id="terminaltype" class="form-control" ng-options="type.name for type in types">                                                                                       
</select>
</div>
```

but how can I set option in my controller.
I used:

```
$("#terminaltype").val($scope.types[0]);
```

and

```
document.getElementById("terminaltype").options[i];
```

but it does not work. Please help me

Answer (score 1):

Can't you set the value inside the model?

You have `ng-model="terminal.terminalType"`

Inside your controller, you just have to set a value to your item.

```
$scope.terminal.terminalType = "someValue";
```

Avoid mixing JQuery and Angular together.